# Having trouble with multiplie IF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested, google-sheets-formula

I'm having problem with some formula I created,
Hello,

I'm having problem with some formula I created,

[image: https://imgur.com/a/lTUX6DY]

for some reason no matter what 
E10 will be it stack on the "2" result,

I want to see if the number is between 100K and 150K the number 3

Comment: Could you post the code instead of an image please

Comment: =IF(AND(E10<=50000),  "1", 
 IF(AND(100000>E10>50000), "2", 
 IF(AND(150000>E10>100000), "3", 
 IF(AND(200000>E10>150000), "4"))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `AND` syntax is wrong. use:

```
=IF(AND(E10<>"",    E10<=50000),  1, 
 IF(AND(E10>50000,  E10<=100000), 2,
 IF(AND(E10>100000, E10<=150000), 3, 
 IF(AND(E10>150000, E10<=200000), 4, ))))
```

and see: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Comment: When i pasted your code it said"Formula parse error."

Comment: @alonc3705  fixed, try now

Answer (score 0):

Use MATCH:

```
=MATCH(E10,{0,50001,100001,150001})
```

MATCH returns a number where the value in E10 falls in the array.  The lower threshold is listed and as soon as the number passes that threshold it moves to the next group.

---

If you really want an `IF` use:

```
=IF(E10<=50000,1,IF(E10<=100000,2,IF(E10<=150000,3,4)))
```

IF resolves serially and will not proceed after finding the first TRUE.

Comment: Can you explain better, please?